# Chrome Extension run JavaScript on newtab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extention I am working on that replaces the Google logo. I have successfully changed it on the main pages, but have noticed that the regular logo is still displayed in the newtab window. I need to find a way to execute some JavaScript to replace the source of that Google logo to the new one. Here is some of the code I am using.

Here is the Manifest.json

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "glogochange",
    "description": "blabla",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "matches": [
                "https://*.google.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "style.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "newlogo.png"
    ]
}
```

And Here is the JavaScript

```
function DoIT() {
    var domain, path, button, logo, ilogo, text, logourl;
    domain = window.location.host;
    path = window.location.pathname;
    logo = document.getElementById("hplogo");
    ilogo = '//*[@id="logo"]/img';
    logourl = chrome.runtime.getURL("newlogo.png");
    button = '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]';
    text = "cool Search";
    if(domain == "www.google.com" && path == "/") {
        XPath(button).value = text;
        logo.srcset = logourl;
        logo.width = 292.5;
        logo.height = 133.5;
        logo.style.display = "block";
    } else if(domain == "www.google.com" && path == "/search") {
        XPath(ilogo).width = 120;
        XPath(ilogo).height = 54;
        XPath(ilogo).srcset = logourl;
        XPath(ilogo).style.display = "block";
    } else if(domain == "www.google.com" && path == "/webhp") {
        XPath(button).value = text;
        logo.width = 292.5;
        logo.height = 133.5;
        logo.srcset = logourl;
        logo.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I tried changing the manifest including:

```
"permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
]
```

And could not get it to 'inject' on the newtab screen. Can someone please help we out with this?

Comment: Another possible solution would be to [override](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) the new tab page. Although not the easier one.

Comment: New tab is protected, your only choice is the override link above.